# React router rendering wrong page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am developing an web app and I am new to react router. Evrything was going great until I found myself in need to render a whole new page, with new navbar and all.

that's my app.js

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
 return (
  <BrowserRouter> 
  <div className='App'>
  <Layout>
  <Header />
  <NavigationB />
  <Search /> 
    <Switch> {/* to swtich to the desired path. Nest all route here */}
    <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
    <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
    <Route path='/register-choice' component={RegisterButton} />
    <Route path='/register-patient' component={RegisterPatient} />
    <Route path='/register-professional' component={RegisterProf} />
    <Route path='/profesional-dashboard' component={ProfessionalDashboard} />
    </Switch>
    </Layout>
  <Footer />
  </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
}
}
```

So, I wanted to go to /professional-dashboard but without rendenring all the components above such and Header, Search, etc.

I tried to go to my index.js file and set it up like this

```
ReactDOM.render(

<BrowserRouter>
<Switch> {/* to swtich to the desired path. Nest all route here */}
<Route path='/' component={App} exact />
<Route path='/professional-dashboard' component= 
{ProfessionalDashboard} />
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>, 

document.getElementById('root'));
```

The idea was, in my form whenever I press register, it should send me to the dashboard of the professional.

At the end of my Register.js file you would find

```
const WrappedRegistrationForm = Form.create()(RegisterProf);

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
<div>
<WrappedRegistrationForm />

</div>
</BrowserRouter>

, document.getElementById('root'));

export default WrappedRegistrationForm;
```

I am using Ant Design, so the form renders WrappedRegistrationForm. At first it was not working then I wrapped it around  BrowserRouter, I don't get the error anymore, but now when I press the register button, it takes me to /professional-dashboard but it loads app.js and not ProfessionalDashboard.js
Funny thing is, if I refresh the page, it loads ProfessionalDashboard.js normally.

Hope I'm explaining myself well.
Glad if you can help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi could try something like this rendering the top one first if its a match if not it will go on to render the rest of the app :) hope this is clear

```
class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <BrowserRouter> 
    <Switch> 
     <Route exact path='/profesional-dashboard' component={ProfessionalDashboard} />
     <StandarRoute path='/' component={MainPage} />
    <Switch /> 
</BrowserRouter>
);
}
}

class MainPage extends Component {
render(){
    return(
      <div className='App'>
          <Layout>
          <Header />
          <NavigationB />
          <Search /> 
            <Switch> {
                <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
                <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route path='/register-choice' component={RegisterButton} />
                <Route path='/register-patient' component={RegisterPatient} />
                <Route path='/register-professional' component={RegisterProf} />
            </Switch>
           </Layout>
           <Footer />
       </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including "exact" before component in your Route, or including "exact" before the 'To' in your Link

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<Route exact path="/register" render={() => ( <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>)
```

Why do you render two times with reactDOM by the way? That might be what’s causing the issue too. Just exporting it and putting it in route component should suffice.